# CSS: The best way to define classes?

Tags: css, class

I'm working on a CSS file with more than 3000 lines.
In this CSS file there are around 40 elements, which have the property display:inline;

Now my question is; wouldn't be better to create a class like:

```
.displayInline {
    display: inline;
}
```

and use it inside the mark-up whenever an element needs to have display: inline; rather than writing the display: inline; 40 times for 40 different elements in the CSS file?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Why would it be better? You'd end up having to say `class="displayInline"` more than `display: inline;`, for one thing. And what if you ended wanting to change one?

Comment: But then there will be more code in the markup. You might also deal with more specificity issues then too. It goes both ways.

Comment: Basically no, it's worse. `[IMHO]`

Comment: If the goal is to, potentially, reduce typing why not use: `.class1, .class2, .class3 /* and so on... */ { display: inline; }? That said this question is still opinion based, and therefore not a good fit for [SO]. Further, this has nothing to do with [tag:css3].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is definitely worse. Indeed what are you talking about is the bad practice, that become somewhat popular with so-called CSS frameworks. Representational information (CSS rules) should not appear in structural part (markup) of code. This is an MVC interruption. By the way, MVC pattern isn't the silver bullet, but in this case there is no reason to ignore it.

Here is a good article on that topic: http://ruby.bvision.com/blog/please-stop-embedding-bootstrap-classes-in-your-html

So, answering your question, it may be fine to try out some CSS preprocessors that support mixins. Native CSS doesn't fit well inner hierarchical tasks. Less or Stylus are quite cool.